# Knex schema not allowing white spaces, semicolons, or eval statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, knex.js

I'm working on a project where i would like to implement good industry security practices that I got from here -> https://medium.com/@nodepractices/were-under-attack-23-node-js-security-best-practices-e33c146cb87d

So for username/password, is there a way to setup the schema for not allowing white spaces, semicolons, and eval statements?

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('employees', function(tbl) {
    // Primary Key 'id'
    tbl.increments('employee_id');

    // Other Columns
    tbl
      .string('username', 128)
      .notNullable()
      .unique();
    tbl.string('display_name', 128).unique();
    tbl.string('password', 128).notNullable();
    tbl.string('email', 255).unique();
    tbl.text('img_url');
    tbl.boolean('is_active').defaultTo(true);
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('employees');
};
```

or should I insert middleware validation in all my POST/PUT endpoints to handle this?